# Error ClassNotFoundException en el return

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, excepciones

el error que encuentro es utilizando una clase que hereda de AsyncTask en Android.

Dentro utilizo una objetos de mi clase User, se comunica con un servidor, maneja los datos... hasta que hago el return y me salta esta excepcion. La clase está importada

```
   protected User doInBackground(Object... values){
     //código de conexión con el servidor
  ObjectInputStream stream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        user = (User) stream.readObject();
        // Aquí puedo obtener todos los datos del usuario
        String received = user.getPhone();
        Log.i("I/TCP Client", "Received " + received);
        Log.i("I/TCP Client", "");
        //cierra conexion
        socket.close();
        //publishProgress(received);
        return user; // y justo cuando llega aquí salta al error
        }catch...
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que es en el `return`? No parece el sitio donde se lanzaría esa excepción. ¿Se muestran los logs?

Comment: He puesto una print después del socket.close() y ahí entra, luego me salta al catch

Comment: ¿ Estas seguro que tu clase User es igual a la que te envían por socket ?

Answer (score 1):

La parte en que te puede salir este error es la siguiente línea:

```
       user = (User) stream.readObject();
```

Este cast es inseguro, porque el objeto que quieres alocar en la variable de tipo User viene del otro lado de la conexión.

Para evitar el error tienes que asegurarte que la clase del objeto serializado y enviado del otro lado de la conexión es idéntica a la clase en el código de tu app donde lo recibes.

Para ser idéntica es importante que hasta el nombre del paquete es igual en la clase. Por ejemplo `server.model.User` y `client.model.User` no son idénticos independiente si el código lo es.